# What is it called when you do something once and benefit from it for a long time or forever

Tags: meaning

Like writing a book or making an album. You do the work once and profit from it continuously. Also when you buy something that will last you a lifetime. You pay a lot of money now but save money in the long run.

I believe it has something to do work, time or money invested upfront or once. I can't remember where I read it, nor can I remember if it was a single word or a two word phrase.

Comment: Enduring, evergreen, perennial, ongoing, permanent, long-lasting.

Comment: It has a *very high return on investment*?

Comment: It's called *capitalism*.

Comment: Whether you sacrificed your time or money, it is basically an *investment*, the word which you used on your own. It also might be a specific case of a statistic term called [long tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail), however long tail distribution in business does not put time on the X axis, although it can. So to "profit on long tail" might as well mean expanding business geographically as in time.

Comment: Perhaps [**resting on one's laurels**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/rest-on-his-laurels.html), not one word, nor two; but that's what the question suggests to me.

Comment: an investment is the opposite of work; you pay money to own say some land (which may pay rent forever).  in contrast if you "writing a book or making an album. You do the work once and profit from it continuously" you pay nothing, but you do work; you then own some "thing" (indeed, intellectual property) which pays "rent" forever.

Comment: You are paid royalties for as long as the work is copyrighted in your name.

Answer (score 3):

In specific regards to performance art, **residuals** are payments made in perpetuity for subsequent broadcasts or showings of your work.

> A residual is a payment made to the creator of performance art for subsequent showings or screenings of the work. A typical use is in the payment of residuals for television reruns. The word is often used in the plural form. - Wikipedia

Comment: This is the only answer which gives a word which indeed is used in connection with the "thing" meant.  If I do a _ _ _ _ job I get residuals forever; in contrast if I just do "work for hire" I only get paid for my work one month at a time.  As I mention in my answer I think surprisingly there's really no word, as such, per se, for this other than the name for "things which generate residuals": intellectual property.

Answer (score 1):

You're ***reaping the rewards***.

> reap: to gain or get (something) as a reward for or result of some action or enterprise [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reap+the+harvest)

Alternately, you could say that you're ***cashing in*** (on some action or enterprise).

> cash in: to obtain a profit or other advantage by timely exploitation [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cash+in)
>
> cash in on: to take advantage of or capitalize on [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cash+in+on)

Comment: No, these simply mean "you made money".  That could be EITHER from residuals, or, just from a totally ordinary month-at-a-time job, or perhaps from say selling something one-time.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using "(long-term) [portfolio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/portfolio)" which means:

> (business) A collection of assets generally.

[Wiktionary]

> A range of investments held by a person or organization:

[[Oxford Online Dictionary]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/portfolio)

Portfolio is not necessarily limited to "stocks/securities" or "bonds" and it can include various things you have for your investment and future returns.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you might be talking about the phrase 'in perpetuity':

> 1. a. in (also for, †to) perpetuity: for all time, for ever; for an unlimited or indefinitely long period.

["perpetuity, n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/141355?redirectedFrom=in+perpetuity (accessed November 14, 2015).]

In the context of your examples:

> - Publishing a book or cutting an album may earn the creator royalties *in perpetuity*.
> - Some work, done once, may earn profits *in perpetuity*.
> - If you buy something that will last a lifetime, you will benefit *in perpetuity*.
> - You may spend more money now, but will save money *in perpetuity*.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question, and (surprisingly) I don't really think there's a single word.

You're essentially talking about moving in to the "I" section of Robert Kiyosaki's Cashfow Quadrant - right?

The only thing that really comes to mind is

## Intellectual Property

You're talking about doing "something" which creates income every year forever (or for a long time) ***with absolutely no effort each further year after the first time***, in contradistinction to, a situation where you simply do work (or whatever) and reap some return that month, and you keep working/earning each month.

If I'm not mistaken the only way you can earn **residuals** (to use the word Chris alerts us to) in this way is with "**IP**" as they say, intellectual property.  So, you make a famous video game, write a famous book, etc.

You said,

## "...Like writing a book or making an album."

indeed those things are literally called "intellectual property" or "IP" if you want to sound cool; there's no other term.

Answer (score 0):

Passive Income. But there’s also residual income and sometimes they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).