# Any idioms that describe actions now that will benefit yourself in the future?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

In regards to the concept of caring about your future self, a simple example being not staying up late drinking so in the morning you don't/your future self doesn't feel awful for work. Is there some phrase that handily captures or illustrates this? Especially if its something that somehow emphasizes the building of the habit and return over time (the more you don't stay up late, the more consistent/reliable for work you are).

The closest I could think of was someone I once heard using "cast your bread upon the waters" and describing how the waves bring it back. Presumably you could consistently cast bread and so receive consistent bread returns at opportune moments but who wants soggy bread (or maybe I don't appreciate this phrase well enough).

To be clear I'm not thinking in terms of literal investment, or at least basic savings/interest idioms don't seem to suit. "A penny saved is a penny earned" for example doesn't quite seem to fit, but if there's something relatively broad that's similar I'm open to it.

This is also not a one time thing like [What is it called when you do something once and benefit from it for a long time or forever](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287034/what-is-it-called-when-you-do-something-once-and-benefit-from-it-for-a-long-time/287049?r=SearchResults&s=1|27.6691#287049)

Comment: ***reap the seeds you sow***?

Comment: Ah, or "you reap what you sow", it's maybe the closest so far.

Comment: ***You reap what you sow***, is not used in the sense of investment. It is usually heard as an admonishment to someone who has done something that has 'come back to bite them in the ass'. US

Comment: I agree, but the basic language expresses the logic of what I'm trying to say. "Reap the seeds you sow" maybe puts a bit more positive spin on it but it's not as snappy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that seems to fit (also mentioned by @Jalene in comments) -

## Reap what you sow

> If someone reaps what they sow, they suffer or *benefit* as a result
> of their own actions. Note: To reap a crop such as corn means to cut
> and gather it. "*Parents who neglect their children will reap what they
> sow.*" "*It seems to me that if we neglect these people in our society, we
> should expect to reap what we sow.*" Note: People sometimes use the more
> formal expressions "***as you sow, so shall you reap***" or "***as we sow, so
> shall we reap***". "*Our future lies in our own hands. Let us ensure that it
> is ethical and spiritual, for without doubt as we sow so shall we
> reap!*" Note: This is based on a quotation from the Bible: `Whatsoever a
> man soweth, that shall he also reap.' (Galatians 6:7)

([The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+reap+what+you+sow))

Comment: Yeah from a pure logical standpoint I agree that this is closest so far (also pretty snappy). Only issue with it is that it's typically used in a negative manner, per the two examples you cited.

Answer (score 1):

A common metaphor would be to say that you are **eating your vegetables** -- doing something that is not what you prefer in the moment because it will have a good effect in the future.

Comment: Is that an English phrase (vs US)? I looked it up and the implication is similar I'll grant, but I was hoping for more emphasis on the returns, like "you reap what you sow".

Comment: @nighliber I'm an American English speaker. I suspect the phrase exists in both American and British dialects. Though "You reap what you sow" could definitely logically mean "sow good seed, get a good crop", in my experience it almost always is used more negatively, like "what goes around, comes around" and "karma is a bitch". If you wanted to use a farming metaphor, "planting seeds for tomorrow" seems to fit better.

Comment: Is it pay your dues?

Comment: @MikeGraham yeah I agree that "reap what you sow" is typically negative, just pointing out the logic of the language more than anything. Also American English, hadn't come across "eat your vegetables" before in the context you meant, no big deal though. "Planting seeds for tomorrow" is better.

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Pay your dues" seems similar to "eat your vegetables", the emphasis is on the work and doesn't reference the returns. It's in the right direction but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @nighliber I disagree with your analysis of the two phrases. Though the words are mostly on the topic of the work, not the returns, the *emphasis* of the idioms is not. The idioms are really about growing up to be big and strong and about collecting the benefits of membership. They are very forward-looking expressions.

Answer (score 1):

*Storing nuts for the winter* is the closest idiom that comes to mind. For some reason, the phrase "*putting up* (as in 'canning') *peaches*" popped into my head. Looked around for a literary reference - but, unsuccessfully. Anyone ever heard of this used as a metaphor in this sense?

Comment: Not bad, in a similar vein to "casting bread upon the waters" only without the sogginess.